# What does it mean Redis URL must specify one of the following schemes (redis://, rediss://, unix://)

Tags: django, redis, channel, daphne

I am getting this error message after a file upload is completed and the redirect is meant to take place.

**Redis URL must specify one of the following schemes (redis://, rediss://, unix://)**

I am not sure what the problem is as i am extremely new to django channels and redis, never used it before so i dont even understand this error.

Basically i have everything from consumers.py,routing.py and a view function to handle file upload.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this error too. In my case, there was a typo issue with the value of the environment variable 'REDIS_URL'.